# How to Get Entire object from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, object, nsdictionary

This is the my data.

```
NSDictionary *dictResponse = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

//Here is dictResponse value is
```

( 
    {

```
    "created_on" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    id = 627;
    "modified_on" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    name = "";
    "user_id" = 99;
},

{

    "created_on" = "2016-05-06 14:43:45";
    id = 625;
    "modified_on" = "2016-05-06 14:43:45";
    name = Ggg;
    "user_id" = 99;
},

{
    "created_on" = "2016-05-03 17:21:52";
    id = 623;
    "modified_on" = "2016-05-03 17:21:52";
    name = Qwerty;
    "user_id" = 99;
},
{
    "created_on" = "2016-04-29 20:12:38";
    id = 601;
    "modified_on" = "2016-04-29 20:12:38";
    name = Teat2;
    "user_id" = 99;
},
{

    "created_on" = "2016-04-29 20:12:27";
    id = 600;
    "modified_on" = "2016-04-29 20:12:27";
    name = Test1;
    "user_id" = 99;
},
{

    "created_on" = "2016-05-09 13:04:00";
    id = 626;
    "modified_on" = "2016-05-09 13:04:00";
    name = Testios;
    "user_id" = 99;
})
```

Now I want to access complete one set object i.e.

```
{

    "created_on" = "2016-04-29 20:12:27";
    id = 600;
    "modified_on" = "2016-04-29 20:12:27";
    name = Test1;
    "user_id" = 99;
}
```

from my **dictResponse**

so when I use
dictResponse[0] or dictResponse[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl9qN.png) .. am getting error, so How can I retrieve entire one set from NSDictionary ?

please check below console log output.
[image]

Comment: The dictionary *(dictResponse)* you posted is not a valid dictionary. Each inner dictionary must be represented by a *key*.

Comment: Your response is an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Right your response is array of dictionaries and you can retrieve entries using it's index as per requirement.

Comment: Yes I know this is not valid dictionary value but it is possible to get something like that value in NSDictionary, so question is not wrong, yes my response is array of dictionary. Means from console log I can give dictResponse[0] and it prints first part as expected.

Comment: @ozgur I have updated my response, added common bracket ()

Comment: @Ganesh what is the problem with piyush patel`s answer ?

Comment: @Mahesh using index not possible, giving error, But am finding right in Piyush's next answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that :

```
id arrResponse = dictResponse;
if ([arrResponse isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && arrResponse != nil && arrResponse != (id)[NSNull null])
{
   NSArray *arrResults =  arrResponse;          
//if you want retrieve specific entries then here is the code for that
for (int i = 0 ; i<arrResults.count; i++) {
       NSString *strName = [[arrResults objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];
       NSString *strCreated_on = [[arrResults objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"created_on"];
       NSString *strModified_on = [[arrResults objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"modified_on"];
       NSInteger userID = [[arrResults objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"user_id"];
       }
   }
```

Comment: Yes this helped!,
Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access objects in a dictionary using an index (like dictResponse[0]). Objects in a dictionary don't have indexes, they have keys. To get an object from a dictionary you use the objectForKey method:

```
NSObject* myObject = [dictResponse objectForKey:@"my_key"];
```

Comment: If `key` is `name` then which name will get ?

Comment: The keys are set when the objects are added to the dictionary. So, as long as the key "Test1" was used when the object with the name "Test1" was added to the dictionary, you can retrieve it with [dictResponse objectForKey:@"Test1"];

Comment: Here `key` is `name` and value is `Test1` so you can't do  `[dictResponse objectForKey:@"Test1"];`

Comment: Here I can get only one set of key!

Answer (score 0):

You have not given enough detail in your question, so the following is a guess:

> so when I use `dictResponse[0]` or `dictResponse[1]` .. am getting error

You never say what error you are getting. I'm guessing you get a *compile* error and not an execution one?

You seem to know your code is wrong as in the comments you write:

> Yes I know this is not valid dictionary value but it is possible to get something like that value in NSDictionary, so question is not wrong, yes my response is array of dictionary. Means from console log I can give dictResponse[0] and it prints first part as expected.

Exactly, you can break the type system and store an array reference into a variable which is typed as holding a dictionary reference, but doing so is not a good idea!

When the compiler sees `dictResponse[0]` it recognises it syntactically as an array indexing operation, so it looks for a method on `dictResponse` which does array indexing. All it knows about `dictResponse`, and remember this is happening *at compiler time*, is that you have stated it is an `NSDictionary *`, so it looks for an array indexing method supported by `NSDictionary` and does not find one, giving the error:

> Expected method to read an array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'

Try correctly typing you variable and see if your code works.

HTH